# i used my http header in the get request for zillow website, and i am not getting the site content

Tags: python, request-headers

i am trying to use get request to get zillow website. after passing in my http headers, i am still not getting what i want. instead of giving me the actual content of the site, it is giving me back the site url

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

google_form = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf7eQN" \
              "Jc8wGK8ZYbVdedP50PKZVBDX9XL9Miku-0yKYiiGhaQ/viewform?usp=sf_link"
zillow = "https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/rentals/?searchQueryState=%7B%2" \
         "2pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22north%22%3A37.915185152" \
         "219706%2C%22east%22%3A-122.22184218359375%2C%22south%22%3A37.635132543862" \
         "206%2C%22west%22%3A-122.64481581640625%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A11%2C%22isMap" \
         "Visible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22price%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A" \
         "872627%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A1%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%" \
         "22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22mp%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A3000%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22val" \
         "ue%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B" \
         "%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn" \
         "%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D" \
         "%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22region" \
         "Id%22%3A20330%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%7D"

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,"
                  " like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,"
              "image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "sec-ch-ua": "'Not/A)Brand';v='99', 'Google Chrome';v='115', 'Chromium';v='115'",
    "Accept-Charset": "utf-8",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
    "Cookie": "PHPSESSID=d54af95d4403aa3ad7d5fae7f8e129a0; _ga=GA1.2.70425315.1692369247;"
              " _gid=GA1.2.1332080711.1692369247; _ga_VL41109FEB=GS1.2.1692371638.2.0.169"
              "2371638.0.0.0",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?o",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
}

response = requests.get(zillow, headers=header)
zillow_web_page = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(zillow, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: FYI, they have an [API](https://www.zillowgroup.com/developers/)

Comment: If you look at `response.text` you'll see that it's mostly JavaScript with a CAPTCHA, there's no actual HTML text.